# How to Execute a Code Block Only if the Script Is Within a Subdirectory?

Tags: powershell

Basically, I've got a block of code that I'll execute *only* if it's within a subdirectory. Here's the code I've been playing with:

if ((Get-Location) -ne "T:\Content\WORK*") {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("You are attempting to run the file outside a subfolder of the T: drive. 
        This will result in errors. 
        Are you sure you wish to continue?","Confirm Execution","YesNoCancel","Warning")
    }

I thought the wildcard operator would be inclusive: meaning it would include the WORK folder and subfolders, but the code block executes in the "WORK" folder and any other folder I execute it in.

Instead, I'd like this message to display if I'm in say... simply \Content or C:. If the condition is false, I'd like to continue execution as normal. Mostly I don't want it to display if I'm in \Content\WORK\Scripts or any other subfolder.

How can I amend this code, in the simplest way, to execute when it returns true that the script (or the current directory) is within a subdirectory of the path?

In case anyone's interested:

```
    if((Get-Location) -NotLike "T:\Content\WORK*"){ 
$Result=[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("You are attempting to run the file outside a subfolder of the T: drive. This could result in errors. Are you sure you wish to continue?","Confirm Execution","YesNoCancel","Warning") switch($Result) { 
"No" {exit} 
"Cancel" {exit} } 
}
```

Comment: `-Like` and `-NotLike` comparison operators ues wildcards.

Comment: You mean to say that -ne doesn't accept wildcards?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: What do you mean? The use case is simply displaying a message under the condition that the code is being executed within a subdirectory of a specified path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

You need to change your condition

From:

`if((Get-Location) -ne "T:\Content\WORK\*"`

To:

`if((Get-Location).path-like "T:\Content\WORK\*"`

EbGreen is correct: `-ne` would evaluate the conditional literally. If you want to evaluate with the wildcard `*` then you need to use `-like`. 
Also, to get the current path you need to add `.path` to `(Get-location)`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'd upvote if I had the reputation. The final code for anyone interested... if((Get-Location) -NotLike "T:\Content\WORK*"){
    
    $Result=[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("You are attempting to run the file outside a subfolder of the T: drive. 
    
This could result in errors. 
    
Are you sure you wish to continue?","Confirm Execution","YesNoCancel","Warning")

    switch($Result) {

    "No" {exit}

    "Cancel" {exit}
    }
}

Comment: ewww...Always edit your question and format it if you want to show more code. Code in the comments sucks...

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to cause such offense. Added it to question.